# Changing text direction to appear from bottom to the top - Confluence

Tags: html, css

I am working on updating the kb articles for one of my clients and due to admin limitation in the portal, I am unable to use the predefined macros.

I have used the css and html to change a text direction but as result it goes from top to bottom which is opposite to what I expected.

How do I change it? :)

Thanks

```css
th { vertical-align: bottom; text-align: center; } th span { -ms-writing-mode: tb-rl; -webkit- 
    writing-mode: vertical-tb; writing-mode: vertical-rl; transform: rotate(180deg); white-space: nowrap; }
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <th><span>Project Sponsor</span></th>
</tr>
</table>
```

[image]

This is what I see now, but I want to have it in opposite direction, from bottom to top

Comment: Can you attach the result image what you want?

Comment: Yes, added what it currently looks like. The text goes from top to bottom lets say, I want each sentence to start at the bottom of table

Comment: With your code I just put a height to table in CSS and I obtain what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the height of the main `article` table and it will go from bottom to top.

```css
th {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  text-align: center;
}

th span {
  -ms-writing-mode: tb-rl;
  -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-tb;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  white-space: nowrap;
}

table {
height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <th><span>Project Sponsor</span></th>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: how about the fixed width? I have tried width: 10vh and/ or 10 vw but it does not do what I expect

Answer (score 2):

If you change rotation from 180deg (text from bottom to top) to 0deg, you obtain text from top to bottom

```css
th { vertical-align: bottom; text-align: center; } th span { -ms-writing-mode: tb-rl; -webkit- 
    writing-mode: vertical-tb; writing-mode: vertical-rl; transform: rotate(0deg); white-space: nowrap; }
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <th><span>Project Sponsor</span></th>
</tr>
</table>
```

Or to obtain the text, who begin at the bottom, put or change the height property in your CSS from `table`